# imagebutton is not visible when I run my code in browser

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2008, imagebutton

I have used an image button which shows calendar on clicking. But while I run the code the Image linked with the image button is not visible, but it is visible in the design mode. I am using visual studio 2008 and c# for coding.

The screenshot of Design mode is shown below :
[image]

The HTML code for this is image button is :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="28px" 
                ImageUrl="~/App_Data/call.jpg" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" 
                style="margin-right: 0px" Width="49px" />
```

And when I run the code in browser the image associated with the ImageButton is not visible. The screenshot of the ImageButton is shown as below :

[image]

Comment: You can do a right click on that, copy image url and see where it actually points to. If you cant oben that image in browser something with your path is wrong.

Comment: noo.. the path is correct.. the image is in App_data folder and its properly pointed.

Comment: What is your Browser telling you? (Developer Tools)

Comment: I have shown the screenshot of the browser... see the second pic

Comment: I was talking aboutz the developer tools in your browser (press F12)

Comment: <!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->   This is what it is showing